# Not able to refactor the code in methods?

Tags: java

I have a scenario where i have four methods containing all the same code except one or two line in try block. Can any suggest how to refactor it?

I tried Enum and switch,but not able to find the correct implementation.
The problem is all methods have different return type.

```
 public static void insertDocument(Test database, Test2 collectionName, Document docToInsert) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = getMongoQueryRetries();
        while (count < maxTries + 1) {
            try {
                addUniqueId(docToInsert);
                database.getCollection(collectionName).insertOne(docToInsert);
                return;
            } catch (MongoTimeoutException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadException | MongoNotPrimaryException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (MongoSocketException | MongoServerException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }

        }

    }


    public static FindIterable<Document> findDocument(MongoDatabase database, String collectionName, Document docToFind) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = getMongoQueryRetries();
        FindIterable<Document> document = null;
        while (count < maxTries + 1) {
            try {
                return database.getCollection(collectionName).find(docToFind);
            } catch (MongoTimeoutException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadException | MongoNotPrimaryException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (MongoSocketException | MongoServerException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return document;
    }


    public static DeleteResult deleteDocument(MongoDatabase database, String collectionName, Document docToDelete) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = getMongoQueryRetries();
        DeleteResult deleteResult = null;
        while (count < maxTries + 1) {
            try {
                deleteResult = database.getCollection(collectionName).deleteOne(docToDelete);
                return deleteResult;
            } catch (MongoTimeoutException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadException | MongoNotPrimaryException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (MongoSocketException | MongoServerException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }

        }

        return deleteResult;
    }


    public static void findAndReplaceDocument(MongoDatabase database, String collectionName, Document docToBeReplaced, Document newDocument) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = getMongoQueryRetries();
        while (count < maxTries + 1) {
            try {
                database.getCollection(collectionName).findOneAndReplace(docToBeReplaced, newDocument);
                return;
            } catch (MongoTimeoutException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadException | MongoNotPrimaryException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (MongoSocketException | MongoServerException e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }

        }
    }
```

Excepted: To have all the logic in one place

Comment: There exists a stack for this exact class of question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Qix Not with the current lack of context though. I'd recommend Kunal reads their [on-topic help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: @Mast agreed. /length

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Two more comments: I just noticed ... A) the first two catch blocks (at least in my example) do the exact same thing. So: that could all go into a single catch block. B) catching Throwable isn'T deemed "good practice". Rather catch Exception. Throwable includes **errors**, and those really shouldnt be caught by such a "low level framework" method. Errors mean: something is really really broken, and that you probably should shutdown altogether. Just logging a Throwable means to **ignore** severe error situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that could be done via a `Callable`, like:

```
public static <T> T processDbAction(Callable<T> dbAction) {
    int count = 0;
    int maxTries = getMongoQueryRetries();
    while (count < maxTries + 1) {
        try {
           return dbAction.call();
        } catch (MongoTimeoutException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadException | MongoNotPrimaryException e) {
            if (++count == maxTries) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (MongoSocketException | MongoServerException e) {
            if (++count == maxTries) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

In other words: you start with such a helper method that puts all the common "framework" around your call. And then you have different implementations of the Callable interface that can focus on their core business, without worrying about retries or exception handling/logging.

Like:

```
public FindAction implements Callable<Document> {
   private final MongoDatabase database;
   private final collectionName;
   private final Document docToFind;
... 

 @Override
 public Document call() throws Exception {
   return database.getCollection(collectionName).find(docToFind);
 }
```

Comment: HI, Will this work for the above methods which have return type as Void

Comment: Well, then it is a `Callable<Void>` . You cant have the same signature return something and return nothing at the same time.

Comment: The way you implemented above,is this some kind of design Pattern?

Comment: @KunalMalhotra I wouldnt call it a design pattern. Just an essential practice in programming: identify the common elements of an operation, and the "different" parts. Then figure how to describe both things, so that you can reduce code duplication.